# Windows Phone 7 - GeoCoordinate.Speed at emulator

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, geolocation, gps

When testing GeoCoordinate Class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0) find that Lovacation.Speed property on emulator return NaN value (latitude, longitude works).

Also test MS sample - http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/geolocation (also NaN value for speed).

What is the best way to emulate\test speed in emulator?

Comment: Are you testing with the Windows Phone 7.1 version of the emulator? And are you having enough points to plot a speed?

Comment: Yes, using 7.1 version. Try near50-100 points (at location tab of emulator)

Answer (score 0):

The basis idea is to create an own implementation for IGeoPositionWatcher. On [SharpGis](http://www.sharpgis.net/post/2010/12/09/Simulating-GPS-on-Windows-Phone-7.aspx) you find one which generates random data from a starting point and calculate the speed based on the traveled distance.
Alternatively if you have a GPX document you can create an implentation which returns the data from the GPX file.

Comment: Thank's. So "Location" tab\instrument of emulator give for application only data about coordinates, without speed?